# Recover data of hard drive possible?

Tags: data-recovery, truecrypt, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, filesystem-corruption

I took out my harddrive (WD 2TB) out of an external casing and put it into an other via usb reading sata docking station which changed something so Windows asks me to format the disk. I got no real experience and knowledge about recovering data from disks unfortunatly and I am not getting any useful information from other persons trys to recover data on other forums and sites.

I got a big truecrypt container on the harddrive which nearly takes all space execpt a little portion where i had a truecrypt.exe laying so i could mount my disk on other systems too. My goal is to restore the disks file system or atleast get this truecrypt container from the disk.

The disk is shown to be "RAW" in the windows Disk Management Tool. This is as narrow as i can describe my problem as my knowdlege allows me to.

I'll post some data about the disk which may be of help for those who understand the information below.

[image: CrystalDiskInfo]

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt partition table. More than likely recoverable, but you never know if there are other issues present. First, I’d recommend taking a clone of the broken disk. You can use something like `dd` from *nix. Have a look at Recuva, it may be able to read the broken partition and extract the container. Otherwise there are lots of tools out there to recover a broken partition. I can’t really recommend any, as it’s been a good few years since I have done this. A google search for `recover hard drive partition` seems to give a few good options (After the adverts of course)

Comment: I used Recuva but all it does is finding files with file extensions which a truecrypt container doesn't have. EaseUS and other software says that i can not use a Partition Recovery on a Unformatted disk :/ @mt025